# Spring MVC: Validation error messages in properties file Doesn't show

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I know this is some how a repeated question, but I followed every advice in this area and couldn't reach a conclusion why it doesn't work:

This is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping("/submitForm")
    String submitForm(
            @Valid
            @ModelAttribute("student")
            StudentRepository student,  BindingResult bindingResult)
    { ...
```

This is the bean definition:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="error-messges"/>
</bean>
```

My Java Object/Bean parameter validation constraint:

```
public class StudentRepository {

    @Size(min = 1,max = 3)
    private String firstName;
    ....
```

And, this is the properties file that should hold the error messages:

```
#typeMismatch.studentRepository.age= Invalid Number
#org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.firstName = First Name Shouldn't Be Empty
Size.student.firstName = Too long text
```

JSP view file:

```
First Name: <form:input type="text" path="firstName" /> <br/>
            <form:errors path="firstName" cssClass="error"/>
```

What could possibly be wrong in this setup?

**Edit:**

Validation is working, and validation messages that are put inline with the validation annotation is working as well, i.e.: `@Size(min=1,message"error")`

What I could get it working is error messages that we fill the properties file with

**Edit 2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<!--  Step 3: Add support for component scanning  -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myCode.springdemo"/>
    <!--
     Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support
    -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <!--  Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver  -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Loading propeties file to be injected in Beans and used in views-->
    <util:properties id="countryOptions" location="classpath:error-messges.properties" />

    <!-- Loading error messages from properties file-->
    <!-- Register the messages properties-->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="error-messges"/>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Comment: Did you try with Size.studentRepository.firstName = "your message"?

Comment: Yes. This is the first thing I did before the current one

Comment: Your `property` in the bean definition has the `value` as `error-messges`, should this be `error-messages`? (missing 'a').

Comment: It has been mistyped from the very beginning, and the IDE auto imported the file name ... So still, this is not the reason

Comment: Please post code as code not as screenshots, that is why there are code formatting options on stackoverflow. Also what doesn't work? Only the messages or the validation at all?

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your notes ... I updated the question, please revisit it

Comment: Where have you defined your `MessageSource` in the `applicationContext.xml` or the `<servlet-name>-servlet.xml`?

Comment: in the servlet file ... I'll update the question with the configuration added